# Apple's 9 digit app ID

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm aware you can find the 9 digit app ID via the App Store, e.g.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/<app name>/id<add id>?mt=8
```

but are there any other ways of getting this? e.g. via Xcode Organizer.

Also, what does that `mt=8` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, it is linked to the Store and is generated there. You can however do this;

Create your app into ItunesConnect and continue until you're ready to upload the binary. At this point you should have the id created. If you go to the app details in the left you should have details including the app id

What does **mt=8;** refer to?

Apple designates a number of different Media Types (mt values):

1   Music

2   Podcasts

3   Audiobooks

4   TV Shows

5   Music Videos

6   Movies

7   iPod Games

8   Mobile Software Applications

9   Ringtones

10  iTunes U

11  E-Books

12  Desktop Apps

Answer (score 0):

The id is for Apple AppStore use, you can't use it in your app. It is only generated once at the time you create a "New App" in iTunes Connect.

To understand this clearly you can say that it can be the primary key in Apple's database of apps on the AppStore.